# Syntax error in Django models file

Tags: python, django

Here Is my code and I am getting this error

```
root@ubuntu:~/public_html/todolist# ./manage.py sql todo
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (models.py, line 28)
```

The code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Todo(models.model):
    name = models.CharField('Name',
    max_lenght =200,
    help_text = 'Enter the project name'                                    )

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)

class TodoArticulo (models.Model):
    fktodo = models.ForeignKey(Todo)
    task = models.TextField('Task', help_text= ' Task Descripcion')
    date = models.DateField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s | %s' % (self.fktodo, self.task)

class Meta:
    verbose_name=  u 'Todo Task'
    verbose_name_plural= 'Todo Tasks'
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation; the code as posted would not work anywhere.

Comment: The argument `max_lenght` in class Todo will also not work as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off there aren't 28 lines in what you posted.

Anyways, in the line where you define verbose_name there shouldn't be a space in between u and the string:

```
>>> u 'Todo Task'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    u 'Todo Task'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> u'Todo Task'
u'Todo Task'
```

Comment: now this is the error    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: You're referring to a non existing variable 'models.model' when you define the Todo class. It should be 'models.Models'

Comment: I change the verbose_name line now and i'm getting this ---- error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model'